# How do I install vs2010 sp1 when I have already vs2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have VS2010 professional that I got from DreamSpark website. Now I'd like to have VS2010 sp1 and I'm a little confuse.

Should I uninstall vs2010 first and install vs2010 sp1? Is the vs2010 sp1 just a component that work on top of vs2010?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can download the [SP1 Installer here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23691).  It upgrades your current VS 2010 to VS 2010 sp1.  You do not need to uninstall VS 2010 - just install the service pack from the above link, and it upgrades you.

Comment: I wish I've asked this question earlier (lol!). Now I've already unistall vs2010. So I'm going to re-install it. Thanks!